# Seperate date part and time part from SimpleDateFormat pattern

Tags: java, simpledateformat

In my UI application, I allow user to specify the Date format as per his choice which I use the same in further processing to format the dates. I want to separate the date part and time part from the pattern that is specified by the user. e.g. user specifies dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss then I would like to divide the date part i.e. dd-MMM-yyyy and time part i.e. HH:mm:ss. I know I can use SimpleDateFormat.toPattern() method which gives me entire format and then can do string manipulation. But I want to avoid that since user may give some ridiculous pattern such as yyyy:HH:ss:dd MMM-mm. In such case it would be very difficult to differentiate what represents date part and what is time part.

Is there a standard java API method which does this? I checked the API but couldn't find it. Is there a third-party API which provides solution to this?

Comment: Would it be possible to separate inputs for date format and time format? If so then your problem does not exist.

Comment: Yes, that is the last option I am also thinking. But I am trying to avoid having two separate inputs when it can be specified with one.

Comment: Can't you just instantinate SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern) and then use sdf.parse(dateString) to get date instance?

Comment: Yes, but I want to separate the date and time part patterns for further processing. So what should be the reason to parse the pattern to get Date?

Comment: Everyhere where you need to make use of the date/time format provided by the user just create instance of SimpleDateFormat and create date from string entered by user.

Comment: @ParagJ How will you use the date and time parts? Should they be strings?

Comment: @ParagJ Also, given the user pattern of yyyy:HH:ss:dd MMM-mm, what should the date and time patterns be when split?

Comment: @user32116 Yes those should be strings. And given the pattern yyyy:HH:ss:dd MMM-mm, I haven't yet decided this (as I am deveoping a general purpose product) but it should be logically yyyy:dd:MMM HH:ss:mm if separator is decided to be ':'.

Comment: @ParagJ If the user wants to see their dates in a certain format, what's the point of splitting the date and time then? If you want the user to see dates and times separately, why not provide 2 inputs, one for the date format and one for the time format?

Comment: @user32116 Ok, I thought I will not specify in detail why do I need this. But since now you have asked this already let me explain you: I am creating a report in which user is expecting date and time parts for some dates and just the date part (but the same that is configured in input) for some dates. Hope that clarifies the requirement now. :)

Comment: @ParagJ Thanks for the clarification, I was just curious. It looks like parsing out the date and time parts from any arbitrary date format is going to be a bit complicated using regex. I would suggest just giving the user 2 input fields to provide them separately, it would be easier for the user as well. You can then combine them when you need to display the full date and time.

Comment: @user32116 Yes, I have decided the same after doing some PoC on this :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can create a Date object, then you can create a Calendar Object.  Then use the `get` methods to retrieve what you are after.

see [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: Ok, sounds good. But user can mix-up the separators e.g. ':' or '-' etc. How to deal with that?

Comment: I am assuming that you are using valid SimpleDateFormat patterns, so you do not need to worry at all.

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. I am developing an application which has UI where user can enter date pattern as per his choice. So it may not be the simpler ones (to test it thoroughly).

Comment: Simply use the Date pattern as per the users request.  If it works (ie is Valid) the you will have a Date Object, then you can create a Calendar Object.